# Why is my controller action being called twice?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller action (please see below) which returns a PDF report/file. I'm using the local URL below to call on this particular action.

http://localhost:35201/Reports/TimeCards/f6c17d29-93fa-4a34-9aa5-d95371253d0d

For some reason, the action is being called twice. Doubling the resource consumption on the server. On the client side, I see two calls on the chrome developer tools. The first call finishes with a 200 and immediately another call is made and marked as cancelled, but the PDF rendering still happens on the server on the second call.

I would like to eliminate the second call to save resources. Has anyone gone through something similar? I would appreciate any help.

```
public ActionResult TimeCards(Guid id)
{
//id = BatchId

//init variables
string sigFile = string.Empty;
Guid company = GetCompanyId();

//get PayrollBatch record
PayrollBatch batch = this.payrollService.GetBatch(id);

//render report this returns a pdf file
byte[] renderedBytes = this.reportService.ProcessTimeCardReport(id, company, this);

return File(renderedBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: So your client code is calling it twice ? Would you care to share that ?

Comment: I got rid of all my client code to test this issue. These are the steps I'm taking.  

1. Run the app locally in debug mode. 
2. Authenticate and close all tabs. 
3. Open a new window (chrome with developer tools showing) to ensure there isn't any JS that could cause the second call. 
4. Paste the URL below.

Please note that I'm not returning any HTML or a View. I'm returning the PDF file itself directly to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an issue in Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587709